# Ошибка цикла в ArrayList's

Tags: java, массивы, строки, циклы

В данный момент хочу написать программу, которая бы заносила текст из txt-файла в двумерный массив `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (массив строк в которых лежат массивы слов).

Цель, добиться на выходе:

```
[ [набор слов 1й строки] [набор слов 2й строки] [ 3й...] [...n] ]
```

У меня в данный момент выходит:

```
[ [набор слов всех строк] [набор слов всех строк] [...] ]
```

Код:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> str = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Text.txt"));

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {  // проверяем, есть ли строка
            String line;           // временная переменная
            line = s.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " "); // дробим строку на слова
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                words.add(st.nextToken()); // заносим слова в ArrayList words
            }
            str.add(words); // заносим  ArrayList words в ArrayList str
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```

Пожалуйста, ткните носом, где ошибка? Как написать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ArrayList всех слов конструируется только один раз, а надо на каждой итерации цикла.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> str = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> words; 
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Text.txt"));

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {  
        words = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = s.nextLine();          
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " "); 
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            words.add(st.nextToken()); 
        }
        str.add(words);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

В вашем же варианте на каждой итерации вы кидаете в `str` ссылку на один и тот же объект `words`, который к концу процесса содержит все слова, которые накапливает.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы не собираетесь добавлять/удалять уже введенные слова, то эффективнее слова каждой прочитанной строки размещать в String[], а не в ArrayList<string>. Размер каждого такого массива можно получить из st.countTokens();

Answer (score 1):

> Как написать правильно?

вот некоторые рекомендации:

```
// эту операцию надо делать до того как выделяем память на обьекты ниже
// в случае если выкинет exception нашей програме пришлось бы выполнить 
// одну абсолютно бесполезную операцию
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Text.txt"));

// используйте интерфейсы вместо реализаций
// для того чтоб изменить arraylist на другую реализацию list 
// достаточно изменения одной сточки
List<List<String>> str = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// обьявлять переменные в цикле плохая примета!
String line;
StringTokenizer st;
List<String> words;

while ( s.hasNextLine() )
{
    words = new List<String>();
    line = s.nextLine();
    // в таких случаях как этот от переменной line можно отказатся
    // (переменная используется лиш один раз)
    // если от этого не страдает читаемость кода (изменить и проверить)
    // при замене нужно добавлять хороший комментарий, напр:
    // строку считанную с консоли готовим к ампутации конечностей :)
    st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        words.add(st.nextToken());
    }

    str.add(words);
}

System.out.println(str);
```